# Orchard Dynamic Forms File Field Upload

Tags: forms, file, dynamic, upload, orchardcms

i want to upload a attachment with Orchard 1.9 Dynamic Forms. There is the Contrib.FileField Module for Custom Forms but i can't add it to Dynamic Forms. Have someone a workaround for Dynamic Forms?

Thanks

Comment: custom forms and dynamic forms are two different features. Custom forms are alao deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

We have created a dynamic forms File Field element. Hope this helps: https://github.com/RiverAgency/River.DynamicForms

After dragging it onto a dynamic form, you'll need to set where the files are saved in the designer.

Dan

Comment: You deserve an award!!! I used your module, but tweaked it a little to use the IStorageProvider for the creation of the file so it uploads the file to the selecte file upload destination (Azure in my case).